# How do I build an xml section and save to file (not a valid xml document per se)

Tags: c#, xml

I´m trying to build a fraction of an XML document, to be included in a final document.
When using `XDocument`, I get an exception:

> "This operation would create an incorrectly structured document."

because my fragment has multiple "root" nodes.

As the file is to be included in a larger document, my base elements will not end up in the root of the final document.

```
XDocument constsDocument = new XDocument(
    new XComment($" Consts section generated on {DateTime.Now} "),
    new XComment($" First group of constants. "),
    FirstTextConsts(MyFirstCollection),
    new XComment($" Refrigerant constants. "),
    SecondTextConsts(MySecondCollection)
    );
// To avoid xml file starting with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> use stringbuilder and StreamWriter.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    Indent = true
};
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xws))
{
    constsDocument.Save(xw);
}
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(_outputFileName);
file.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); 
file.Close();
```

EDIT 1: 
The two methods called within the creation of the document (in principal):

```
private static IEnumerable<XElement> FirstTextConsts(IEnumerable<MyClass> collection)
{
    return collection.Select(r => new XElement("const", 
            new XAttribute("name", $"IDENTIFIER_{r.Id}"),
            new XAttribute("translatable", "false"),
            new XElement("text",
                new XAttribute("lang","en"), r.Name)));            
}

private static IEnumerable<XElement> SecondTextConsts(IEnumerable<MyClass> collection)
{
    foreach (var obj in collection)
    {
        if (obj.SomeSelector)
            yield return new XElement("const", 
                new XAttribute("name", $"IDENTIFIER_{r.Id}"),
                new XAttribute("translatable", "false"),
                new XElement("text",
                    new XAttribute("lang","en"), r.Name)));            
        if (obj.SomeOtherSelector)
            yield return new XElement("const", 
                new XAttribute("name", $"IDENTIFIER_{r.Id}"),
                new XAttribute("translatable", "true")
                );            
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
As I really need the flexibility of XDocument to build a multilevel xml document wit helper methods returning IEnumerable on different levels, I decided to add a phony  element and remove it again before writing to file:

```
XDocument constsDocument = new XDocument(
    new XElement("root", 
        new XComment($" Consts section generated on {DateTime.Now} "),
        new XComment($" First group of constants. "),
        FirstTextConsts(MyFirstCollection),
        new XComment($" Refrigerant constants. "),
        SecondTextConsts(MySecondCollection)
        )
    );
```

Before writing to file i strip the  element:

```
    file.WriteLine(sb.ToString().Replace("<root>" + Environment.NewLine, "").Replace(Environment.NewLine + "</root>", ""));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't create an `XDocument` that is invalid (due to the multiple "root" nodes). You therefore need to create a list of nodes, and write those to the document fragment.

```
var constsDocument = new List<XNode> {
           new XComment($" Consts section generated on {DateTime.Now} "),
           new XComment($" First group of constants. "),
           new XElement("example"),
           new XComment($" Refrigerant constants. "),
           new XElement("another")
};
// To avoid xml file starting with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> use stringbuilder and StreamWriter.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    Indent = true,
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
};
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xws))
{
    foreach (var element in constsDocument)
    {
        element.WriteTo(xw);
    }
}
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(_outputPath);
file.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
file.Close();
```

---

EDIT: to use a method which returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>` inside the object initializer for the `List`, you would have to change the definition slightly and the way you add the other items:

```
var constsDocument = new List<IEnumerable<XNode>> {
    new [] { new XComment($" Consts section generated on {DateTime.Now} ") },
    new [] { new XComment($" First group of constants. ") },
    FirstTextConsts(MyFirstCollection),
    new [] { new XComment($" Refrigerant constants. ") },
    SecondTextConsts(MySecondCollection)
);
```

...

```
foreach (var element in constsDocument.SelectMany(n => n))
```

Comment: I have edited my question to illustrate the two methods that are called during document creation. They won't work in an object initializer, as you suggest?

Comment: @TheRoadrunner I have just updated my answer with one possible solution to using your two methods that return multiple `XElement` instances.

Comment: Thank you very much for your update. It works the way you suggest.

Comment: I ended up going back to XDocument and added a phony <root> element, that I then strip out of the stringbuilder before witing to file. The reason is that your sugested solution only supports calling my helper methods on first level, whereas in real life, I call helper methods also in deeper levels.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare that you want XML to be just a fragment and switch from XDocument to XMLDocument:

```
XmlDocument constDocument = new XmlDocument();
constDocument.CreateComment(" Consts section generated on {DateTime.Now} ");
constDocument.CreateComment(" First group of constants. ");
FirstTextConsts(MyFirstCollection); // Need to be adapted
constDocument.CreateComment(" Refrigerant constants. ");
SecondTextConsts(MySecondCollection); // Need to be adapted
XmlDocumentFragment fragDocument = constDocument.CreateDocumentFragment();
fragDocument.InnerXml = "<const>fragment</const><const>fragment2</const>"; // Need to be adapted

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment,
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    Indent = true
};
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xws))
{
    fragDocument.WriteContentTo(xw);
}
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(_outputFileName);
file.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); 
file.Close();
```

or add aritificial root element:

```
"<aritificialroot>" + fragment + "</aritificialroot>"
```